# How to disable combobox based on other combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have 2 combobox in a same wpf window. The first item in first combobox is selectversion and it is selected by default(isselected=true). Now i need the second combobox to be disabled if the first item of first combobox is selected Otherwise enabled.

I tried following,

```
If(absversion.selectedindex !=0) 

  Secondcombo.isenabled=false://here i am getting null reference exception 

Else
  Secondcombo.isenabled = true:
```

In `page_loaded` event I have,

```
Secondcombo.isenabled = false //so that Secondcombo will be disabled by default wen loaded.
```

Could anyone please help me,to get this done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to do this in XAML than in codebehind:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ComboBox1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox1, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It worked!! I am absolutely new to wpf. It really reduced my search time.